# Можете пожалуйста помочь, напишите что у меня не так. Я хочу что бы статьи были слева, а комментарии справа, но ничего не работает

Tags: html, css

Можете пожалуйста помочь, напишите что у меня не так. Я хочу что бы статьи были слева, а комментарии справа, но ничего не работает.

```css
body {
    background-image: url(assets/jpeg/background.jpg); 
}

.title {
 color: #000000;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
    display: flex;

}

.title_1 {
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
    display: flex;
 transition: 2s all;
}

.title_1:hover {
    background: #5c8a4c;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#t2 {
 color: #000000;
 margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
    transition: 2s all;
}

#t2:hover {
    background: #5c8a4c;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

#t3 {
 color: #000000;
 margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
    transition: 2s all;
}

#t3:hover {
    background: #5c8a4c;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

#t4 {
 color: #000000;
 margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
    transition: 2s all;
}

#t4:hover {
    background: #5c8a4c;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.background {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #999;
}

.comments {
    margin-right: 150px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 200px;
 background: #454545;
}

.comments_1 {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
}

.comments_2 {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
}

.comments_3 {
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
 background: #454545;
}

.article_all {
}

.article_1 {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    background: #575757;
}

#title_article_1 {
 color: #dbdbdb;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

#text_article_1 {
 margin-left: 35px;
}


.article_2 {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    background: #575757;
}

#title_article_2 {
 color: #dbdbdb;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

#text_article_2 {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.article_3 {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 70%;
    background: #575757;
}

#title_article_3 {
 color: #dbdbdb;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

#text_article_3 {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.article_4 {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 70%;
 background: #575757;
}

#title_article_4 {
 color: #dbdbdb;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

#text_article_4 {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.article_5 {
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 70%;
 background: #575757;
}

#title_article_5 {
 color: #dbdbdb;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

#text_article_5 {
 margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Блог IT програмиста.</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body class="body"> 
            <div class="title">
                <div class="title_1">
                    <a href="index.html" id="t1_1"><i><b><h1>Блог</h1></b></i></a>
                    <a href="index.html" id="t1_2"><i><b><h1>  IT  </h1></b></i></a>
                    <a href="index.html" id="t1_3"><i><b><h1>програмиста</h1></b></i></a>
                </div>
                <a href="index.html" id="t2"><h2>Главная страница</h2></a>
                <a href="https://vk.com/higek" target="_blank" id="t3"><h2>Я в ВК</h2></a>
                <a href="#" id="t4"><h2>Помощь</h2></a>
            </div>
            <div class="background">
                    <div class="comments" align="right">
                        <p id="comment_main"><h1>Комментарии:</h1></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article_1" align="left">
                        <p id="title_article_1"><h1>СХД HP MSA P2000 G3 Modular Smart Array и учётные данные по умолчанию.</h1></p>
                        <p id="text_article_1"><h2>В конфигурации по умолчанию у контроллеров управления системы хранения данных HP MSA P2000 G3 имеется несколько встроенных учётных записей. Пароли этих учётных записей любой вменяемый администратор сменит при первой же настройке контроллеров управления. Однако, даже много лет проработав с подобной железкой, и предполагая, что в этой области нет никаких "белых пятен", в один прекрасный день можно открыть для себя совершенно удивительные и неизвестные ранее подробности, от которых на голове могут зашевелиться волосы.</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comments_1" align="right">
                        <p id="author1" align="left"><i><h2>Arthur Sharifov</h2></i></p>
                        <p id="text_comment1" align="left"><h2>Блин, реально помогло, спасибо!</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="article_2" align="left">
                            <p id="title_article_2"><h1>Базовая настройка брандмауэра Debian GNU/Linux 10 Buster с помощью nftables.</h1></p>
                            <p id="text_article_2"><h2>Согласно документа в Debian Wiki фреймворк nftables представляет собой механизм, используемый ОС Debian 10 Buster по умолчанию для управления встроенного в ядро Linux брандмауэра Netfilter. Nftables может рассматриваться, как современная, более продвинутая и функциональная замена таким инструментам, как iptables, ip6tables, arptables и ebtables.</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comments_2" align="right">
                        <p id="author2" align="left"><i><h2>Storm Python</h2></i></p>
                        <p><h2 id="text_comment2" align="left">Впервые тут, но все советы серьёзно работают! Особенно помогла установка RSAT, неверил, но это так. Вообщем советую.</h2></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="article_3" align="left">
                        <p id="title_article_3"><h1>Установка Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) в Windows 10 v1903 в Offline-режиме.</h1></p>
                        <p id="text_article_3"><h2>Ранее мы уже писали об особенностях установки пакета Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) в Windows 10. Но время идёт и новые релизы Windows 10 вносят новые правила работы с этим пакетом. В этой заметке мы поговорим об особенностях автономной установки RSAT в актуальной версии Windows 10 1903.</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comments_3" align="right">
                        <p id="author3" align="left"><i><h2>Checker Maxim</h2></i></p>
                        <p id="text_comment3" align="left"><h2>Вы серьёзно?! Помойму это полный бред!!! Почти все замечания полная фигня!!!!!!!!!!! Прошу, уходите от сюда!!!!!!</h2></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="article_4" align="left">
                        <p id="title_article_4"><h1>Отключение и завершение простаивающих сеансов на серверах Remote Desktop Session Host в зависимости от дня месяца и членства в доменной группе.</h1></p>
                        <p id="text_article_4"><h2>Как правило, для отключения неактивных и завершения отключенных сессий на серверах сеансов служб удалённых рабочих столов Remote Desktop Session Host в Windows Server 2012 R2 администраторы используют возможности групповых политик домена Active Directory. Однако иногда может возникать потребность в управлении неактивными сеансами по хитрым правилам, которые невозможно уложить в рамки стандартных механизмов GPO или даже GPP. В таких случаях для управления сеансами можно прибегнуть к возможностям PowerShell.</h2></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="article_5" align="left">
                        <p id="title_article_5"><h1>Несколько замечаний по установке SharePoint Server 2016 на Windows Server 2012 R2 c размещением БД в SQL Server 2016.</h1></p>
                        <p id="text_article_5"><h2>В целом мероприятия по подготовке инфраструктуры и первичному развёртыванию фермы SharePoint Server 2016 на Windows Server 2012 R2 похожи на те, что ранее были описаны в заметках о SharePoint 2013 про установку кластера SQL Server и создание новой фермы SharePoint. Разумеется, в случае с SharePoint 2016 есть свои нюансы, о которых тезисно будет отмечено в этой заметке.</h2></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не очень понятна сама идея, что вы хотите получить в итоге? Вот тут немного оптимизировал ваш код, убрал задвоения одинаковых классов и id https://jsfiddle.net/namk0txo/

Comment: Да, не совсем понятно, каков должен быть конечный вид. Ну и почитай про свойство `display: flex` и как с ним можно работать, а то ты его применяешь к каждому блоку обертке, но как я вижу, совсем не понимаешь как с ним работать.